# Laravel 5 - No query results for model but not using a model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model

I'm new to Laravel 5 and I have the following error when trying to load a view :

1/2

```
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
No query results for model [App\Article].
```

2/2

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 303:
No query results for model [App\Article].
```

The url is : http://domain.com/admin/articles/create

Route :

```
Route::get('/admin/articles/create', 'AdminController@create');
```

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Article;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function home() {
        return view('admin.home');
    }


    public function create() {
        return view('admin.articles.create');
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it works for 'AdminController@home' and not for 'AdminController@create' nor the error because I don't call the model 'Article'.

View file 'create.blade.php' in \project-name\resources\views\admin\articles

```
@extends('layouts.admin.admin_template')
```

admin_template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->




<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ $page_title or "Project Name" }}</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}    
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.0/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
          page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
          apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
    -->
    <link href="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="skin-blue">
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
    @include('layouts.admin.header')

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    @include('layouts.admin.sidebar')

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                {{ $page_title or "Page Title" }}
                <small>{{ $page_description or null }}</small>
            </h1>
            <!-- You can dynamically generate breadcrumbs here -->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
                <li class="active">Here</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
            @yield('content')
        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    @include('layouts.admin.footer')

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{{ asset ("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
      Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
      user experience -->
</body>
</html>
```

Footer

```
<!-- Main Footer -->
<footer class="main-footer">
    <!-- To the right -->
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        Anything you want
    </div>
    <!-- Default to the left -->
    <strong>Copyright © 2016 <a href="#">Optimads</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
</footer>
```

Header

```
<!-- Main Header -->
        <header class="main-header">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="/admin" class="logo"><b>Admin</b>LTE</a>

            <!-- Header Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </a>
                <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                        <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                            <!-- Menu toggle button -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                <span class="label label-success">4</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- inner menu: contains the messages -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- start message -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <!-- User Image -->
                                                    <img src="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg") }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
                                                <h4>
                                                    Support Team
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <!-- The message -->
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end message -->
                                    </ul><!-- /.menu -->
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li><!-- /.messages-menu -->

                        <!-- Notifications Menu -->
                        <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                            <!-- Menu toggle button -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                                <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- start notification -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end notification -->
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Tasks Menu -->
                        <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
                            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
                                <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- Inner menu: contains the tasks -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- Task item -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <!-- Task title and progress text -->
                                                <h3>
                                                    Design some buttons
                                                    <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                                                </h3>
                                                <!-- The progress bar -->
                                                <div class="progress xs">
                                                    <!-- Change the css width attribute to simulate progress -->
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end task item -->
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer">
                                    <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- User Account Menu -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
                                <img src="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg") }}" class="user-image" alt="User Image"/>
                                <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
                                <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- The user image in the menu -->
                                <li class="user-header">
                                    <img src="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg") }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                                    <p>
                                        Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                                        <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Body -->
                                <li class="user-body">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Followers</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Sales</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Friends</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Footer-->
                                <li class="user-footer">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Sidebar

```
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
        <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
                <img src="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg") }}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
                <p>Alexander Pierce</p>
                <!-- Status -->
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- search form (Optional) -->
        <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type='submit' name='search' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- /.search form -->

        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">HEADER</li>
            <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
            <li class="active"><a href="/admin/articles/"><span>Articles</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Another Link</span></a></li>
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><span>Multilevel</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

In kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\MustBeAdministrator::class,
    ];
```

MustBeAdministrator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MustBeAdministrator
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // $request will return null if user is not signed in
        $user = $request->user();
        if ($user && $user->status == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'No way.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets see if you delete line `use App\Article;` error still occurs.
And one more question, in the view file, ur not doing something with models ?

Comment: If I delete 'use App\Article;' I have the error : 'Class App\Http\Controllers\Article does not exist'.

In the view file, I'm only trying to load the admin layout.

Comment: show me your view file and admin middleware file

Comment: I have updated the first post, the admin.articles.create view is exactly the same than admin.home

Comment: There might be many reasons for that. The code might be executed somewhere else. Are you sure you don't have for example view composer created that tries to find some article?

Comment: When I try to load the view 'admin.home' with 'AdminController@createarticle' it doesn't work neither. 


I found something interesting, if I change the route from Route::get('/admin/articles/create', 'AdminController@createarticle'); to Route::get('/admin/create', 'AdminController@createarticle'); the view loads properly.


It might be that when 'articles' is included in the route, Laravel tries to load the model?

Comment: Found this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: If I change the url to : project-name/admin/abrticles/create (articles -> abrticles), it works...

Comment: Ok guys I got it... Route::get('/admin/articles', 'AdminController@articleshome');
Route::get('/admin/articles/{permalink}', 'AdminController@editarticle');
Route::get('/admin/articles/create', 'AdminController@createarticle'); The app tries to find 'create' in App\Article...